# Avoiding Global variables in FastAPI managing a python subprocesses

Tags: subprocess, global-variables, fastapi, recording, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI app that is meant to control multiple video recording processes. To do so, I've wrapped a binary command line recording app (provided in the [NDI SDK](https://ndi.video/tech-page/)) in python and am controlling the recording app via subprocess.POPEN and stdin in my FastAPI app.

To manage this, I'm using a global dict `recording_processes` to store the processes created with POPEN so that I can later interact with them via `stdin` during the recording (split the files every 10mins & stop the recording).

Running FastAPI with Uvicorn I discovered that if I force 1 worker, this works as I'd like, but when using multiple workers, they don't share memory and some workers won't have access the processes I've created with POPEN.

I'd really like to use multiple workers here; what options would I have to manage these recording subprocesses with multiple Uvicorn workers?

Here's some simplified code for better understanding of my problem:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import subprocess
import shlex
import datetime

app = FastAPI()

recording_processes = {}

class RecordingProcess:
    def __init__(self, stream_name, save_dir, app_dir):
        self.stream_name = stream_name
        self.save_dir = save_dir
        
        time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

        command = '"' + app_dir + '" -i "' + stream_name + \
            '" -o "' + self.save_dir + '-' + time + '"'

        self.process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),
                                        shell=False,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        universal_newlines=True)

        self.chop_index = 1
        self.timer = RepeatTimer(10 * 60, self.chop_now)
        self.timer.start()

    def stop_recording(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.process.stdin.write('<exit/>\n')
        self.process.stdin.close()
        self.process.poll()

    def chop_now(self):
        self.chop_index += 1
        time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        self.process.stdin.write(
            '<record_chop filename="' + self.save_dir + '-' + time + '"/>\n')
        self.process.stdin.flush()

class RepeatTimer(threading.Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

@app.get("/startrecording/{stream_name}")
async def startrecording(stream_name):
    is_recording = stream_name in recording_processes

    if not is_recording:
        recording_processes[stream_name] = RecordingProcess(stream_name=stream_name,
                                                            save_dir=recording_path,
                                                            app_dir=ndi_sdk_bin_path)

    return not is_recording

@app.get("/stoprecording/{stream_name}")
async def stoprecording(stream_name):
    is_recording = stream_name in recording_processes

    if is_recording:
        recording_processes[stream_name].stop_recording()
        recording_processes.pop(stream_name)

    return is_recording
```

Comment: It might be easier to scale this by separating the two - i.e. have separate worker processes that your web interface communicates with through a pubsub-channel or something similar. That means you can also scale it with multiple node pools later, instead of relying on multiple workers sharing memory inside a uvicorn process (which should, generally, only be concerned with the web interface). Using redis with its pubsub interface might be a good choice, but you might already have something in your stack that supports a pubsub architecture?